# Unresolved External Symbol x86 Assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, irvine32

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword
DumpRegs PROTO

.code
main proc
     mov cx, 01h
     sub cx, 2
     call DumpRegs
     add cx, 2 ; Clears the sign flag
     invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Errors:

```
1>Example.obj : warning LNK4258: directive '/ENTRY:main@0' not compatible with switch '/ENTRY:main'; ignored
1>Example.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DumpRegs@0 referenced in function _main@0
1>C:...: fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I tried looking up how to resolve this issue but have had no luck. Can anyone help me get this thing running?

SOLUTION: For those using Kip Irvine's book and trying to get their stuff to work, you can find how to create a project from scratch using the libraries in his book here (bottom): http://kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2013/index.htm

Note that it is below his first two entrys on how to create a program which makes it somewhat difficult to find.

Comment: How did you assemble and link? And where is the body of `DumpRegs`?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio with the settings found a Youtube video... What do you mean the body of DumpRegs? I thought it was a system call.

Comment: What is `DumpRegs`? Where it was declared?

Comment: What exactly are those settings that you found in the video. And, no, `DumpRegs` is most likely a procedure from some library that they use in whatever tutorial it is that you're following.

Comment: Well, I'm learning from Kip Irvine's book but I needed to configure Visual Studio so I used this video... The video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWWTrdNkhBI

Comment: Questions should be as self-contained as possible, so it's better that you include all relevant information in your question instead of linking to off-site resources.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the library that has the dumpregs process using INCLUDE and INCLUDELIB.